# How do I set the string 'text1' as selected item to combobox which contain items text1,text2,test3?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a string "test1" and my databound comboBox named ddlBrands contains test1, test2, and test3. How do I set the selected item to "test1"? That is, how do I match my string to one of the comboBox items?

```
string brand = MainClass.getBrandOfProductFromDB(Convert.ToInt32(this.lblProductId.Text));
```

I tried the following codes one by one but it did not worked:

```
ddlBrand.SelectedIndex = ddlBrand.FindStringExact(brand);
ddlBrand.SelectedIndex = ddlBrand.FindString(brand);
ddlBrand.SelectedIndex = ddlBrand.Items.IndexOf(brand);
ddlBrand.Text = brand;
ddlBrand.SelectedItem = brand;
ddlBrand.SelectedText = brand;
```

Comment: With `ddlBrand.SelectedItem` you probably have to call `ToString()`.

Comment: Just set the ddlBrand.SelectedIndex = 0; as last line of your code.

Comment: Show how you are populated combobox with the data?